# How to assign a value to Request which is of httprequest usercontrol in unit testing?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, user-controls, httprequest

I have a method which uses the Request.UrlReferrer.Host in the masterpage.asx.cs.

```
protected string DoSomething()
{
  Request.UrlReferrer.Host is used
//Request is of httprequest usercontrol
}
```

I am trying to write a unit test case for this method.

and having a call target.DoSomething() but The Request is having null value. How can I give it a value so that the DoSomething() method doesn't break?

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to recommend a different approach, since these values are not settable inside `HttpRequest`.

Write a class whose sole responsibility is to deal with the `HttpRequest` and produce the appropriate output. Then extract an interface from that class. `DoSomething` would then depend upon that interface. For your test, you would be able to provide a "fake," or a stand-in implementation that can serve data that the method would then use in its logic.

For example, you might have an interface like

```
interface ICanHandleRequest { }
```

So you can then have in your production code an implementation that your DoSomething method would normally use.

```
class RequestHandler : ICanHandleRequest { }
```

But for your test, you would create a different implementation so that your DoSomething method can be tested.

```
class TestHandler : ICanHandleRequest { }
```

You could also use mocking libraries (such as [Rhino Mocks](http://hibernatingrhinos.com/open-source/rhino-mocks), for example) to build such fakes, if you so choose. The idea is that `DoSomething` doesn't need to know how to use `HttpRequest`, it has other responsibilities. It simply needs the output. In production, that data would come from your real class, and it would use `HttpRequest`. For testing, you can simply substitute the implementation with something that can produce data that would be appropriate for your test. Make sense?